# Eclipse directory templates

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

Is there a way in Eclipse to create a directory template so that any time someone creates a folder at a certain position in the filesystem, a nested subdirectory is automatically created underneath it?

For example, if I have a project MyProject:

```
MyProject

--src

--properties

     --plugins
```

Anytime someone creates a folder under 'plugins', I want to generate a subdirectory of say 'folderA, folderB, folderC' so that all they have to do is create a folder under plugins (i.e. myFolder) and this is generated:

```
MyProject

--src

--properties

     --plugins
        -- myFolder
           --folderA
           --folderB
           --folderC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Eclipse plugin that registers resource change listener in workspace. From these change notifications you can figure out if user creates particular kind of folder.

There is very good article in eclipse.org about resource change listeners:
[here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html)

basically you just implement IResourceChangeListener interface, add that to workspace and go through the events you receive, and act if some rules match.

Code snipet stolen from the article

```
   IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
   IResourceChangeListener listener = new IResourceChangeListener() {
      public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
         System.out.println("Something changed!");
      }
   };
   workspace.addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

if you don't have experience in creating eclipse plugins, there are good article:

eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

Comment: Thank you.  I will take a look.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution other than implementing plugin, could be:

Add builder (ant, program) on your project (when your builds are done automatically). Your program would be checking the directory and creating folders if they are missing.

Comment: Actually, that is what I have it doing now, but I wanted it at the time of folder creation as opposed to build time.  Thank you for the help, though.